# Cant find gcloud utility using MAMP

Tags: gcloud, kubernetes

After attempting to innitialize cluster/kube-up via php using the following code from my local virtual host:

```
$old_path = getcwd();
chdir('/Users/username/kubernetes');
$output = shell_exec('cluster/kube-up.sh');
chdir($old_path);

print_r("<pre>$output</pre>") ;
```

I received the following error:

```
Can't find gcloud in PATH.  Do you wish to install the Google Cloud SDK? [Y/n]
```

I have gcloud available in my bash_profile. I am also running MAMP and included the path variable in /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/envvars_* and envvars-std -

I am still getting this prompt. Any ideas?

Comment: If you run `shell_exec('gcloud version')` does that find gcloud in your path?

Comment: Hi Robert, the output I receive:     

     "sh: gcloud: command not found"

Answer (score 0):

I managed to bypass this by doing the following:

1. I created a script file in my local kubernetes directory.
2. In the script, I inserted the following code:

   `export PATH="/Users/username/google-cloud-sdk/bin:$PATH"`

   `cluster/kube-up.sh`

This then ran kube-up.sh creating a cluster with values I had set in `kubernetes/cluster/gceconfig-default.sh` using php.